# EF Core - Add Unique Constraint

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, constraints, unique

I'd like to add unique constraint using model builder in ASP.NET Core

- .NET 5
- EF Core 5..

Here is what I found:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Ticker>()
            .HasIndex(r => r.Name)
            .IsUnique();
```

However after updating database it adds index instead of constraint.
Is there the way to add constraint?
Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although you use `.HasIndex(r => r.Name).IsUnique()`,it will create a unique `Index` instead of `Constraint`. But the effect are the same. It will prevent you adding duplicated value for `Name`.

> However after updating database it adds index instead of constraint. Is there the way to add constraint?

If you must add `Constraint`, I suggest you use `HasAlternateKey` method which enables you to create an alternate key by placing a unique constraint:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Ticker>()
           .HasAlternateKey(r => r.Name);
```

Then you can see it adds the unique constraint like below in database:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helps.